# React: Does using arrow functions in Functional Components result in more re-rendering?

Tags: reactjs, components, arrow-functions

Using `Class-based Components` we are able to `bind` in the state because well, there is a `state`,  thus causing less re-rendering.

`Functional Components` do not offer this functionality because in order to use `state` we need `Hooks`, and with `Hooks`, the component gets the power of `state` without having one.

**My question is:**

When it comes to the overall App, does the use of `arrow functions` (`=>`) within `Functional Components` result into increased re-rendering?

Comment: Can you give us a code example of something that you are concerned would cause extra rerenders?

Comment: the bind trick is made for the `this` object to refer to the class instead of the caller... it does not cause less re rendering.

Answer (score -1):

Alright, an [arrow function is a short syntax alternative to a regular function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
They don't have their own bindings to the `this`, `arguments`, `super`, or `new.target` keywords.

**Arrows functions is plain simple `ES6`, it has nothing to do with `react` functionality.**

**In fact, the [Component lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)  in `react` is affected by `state` and `props`.**

So, except in the parts where call `setState` within `() => ()`, the arrow functions HAVE NO direct or indirect impact your component rendering/updating.

Comment: I digress. I am aware of what you mentioned regarding arrow functions. However, when arrow functions are used to bind a functionality, say any `handleChange()` to the state, we can either do it inline - using an arrow function `() => ()` - or bind  `handleChange()` in the component - causes less re-rendering.  At least that's what I know.

Comment: Unless otherwise, I suspect you are referring to an issue of "[Handling events in React](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)". And even then the react-team makes it clear that the two approaches achieve the same result. But i'll say, if `state` is not updated in any `arrow` function, there is no effect on component rendering. Please share a link to what you mentioned. I'd like to read some more about it too...